# How to get array of Vec<i64> from a array of JoinHandle<Vec<i64>>?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to learn multithreads but I'm stuck on this situation:

```rust
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let numbers = vec![15i64, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0];
    let total_threads = 4;
    let mut slices = Vec::with_capacity(total_threads);
    let size_slice = numbers.len() / total_threads;

    for k in 0..total_threads {
        let slice = numbers[size_slice * k..size_slice * (k + 1)].to_vec();
        slices.push(slice);
    }

    let mut handles = Vec::new();

    for slice in slices.iter() {
        let mut new_slice = slice.to_vec();

        new_slice.push(5);
        let handle: thread::JoinHandle<Vec<i64>> = thread::spawn(|| {
            // Example without sorting, because the problem is the same
            new_slice
        });

        handles.push(handle);
    }

    let mut new_numbers = Vec::new();
    for handle in handles.iter() {
        new_numbers.push(handle.join().unwrap());
    }

    println!("{:?}", new_numbers);
}
```

Which is giving me the error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*handle` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:30:26
   |
30 |         new_numbers.push(handle.join().unwrap());
   |                          ^^^^^^ move occurs because `*handle` has type `JoinHandle<Vec<i64>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I would like to ask how may I proceed here, or if there is a right way to do this.

The object of the program is to do merge sort simultaneously in various vectors.

Comment: `for handle in handles {...}`

Comment: I edited it, is it better?

Comment: okay, the solution of trentcl worked but I wanted to make this question better for future use. I think the code is alright now, @Stargateur.